# setting up gerrit

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, gerrit

I have found the documentation on installing Gerrit to be not very good. Managing databases is not my strong suit so it is not too friendly to me.

What I have:

I have the gerrit.war file sitting on my desktop and a AWS server running Ubuntu.

Reading over the install guide I see all these commands they want me to run, but I am not exactly sure where I am doing this. On the server? Some terminal?

I know this is probably nooby, but I am getting frustrated.

Any help or documentation would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The commands must be run on the server.

First copy the gerrit.war file to the server (via scp, ftp, or whatever upload method AWS provides), and then using a terminal execute the commands as shown in the documentation.